# How do I use IFileOperation?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use IFileOperation to copy files.

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  but I don't understand them.

Can `IFileOperation` call a progress method with information about each item that was copied out of those given to it – considering a folder as one instead of every file in it as separate ?

EDIT:
I have a `List<string>` of files and folders that I want to copy to `string` folder, with a method being called to report progress. How do I actually do that?

Is this managed code? Is there anything I should be careful with, more than "standard" code?

Comment: What do you not understand? And yes this is unmanaged COM. It's much easier to call `SHFileOperation`, for what it's worth.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have a `List<string>` of files and folders that I want to copy to `string` folder, with a method being called to report progress. How do I actually do that?

Comment: P/invoke to SHFileOperation and let the system show the progress dialog which will look much better and feel more integrated than writing your own dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this managed code?

No.  `IFileOperation` is part of the [Windows Shell API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is a COM interface.  You'll need to use COM interop if you want to use these interfaces.

You can get a total progress by using [CopyItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample code? I checked [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/), but nothing there.